# What is the texture painting workflow for theme colors?

Tags: texture-painting, unity

I want to create hand painted 3D models for game development that supports change of theme colors. What is the correct workflow as a 3D artist? (I am not a 3D artist, yet. I am learning unity + blender)

*For example, a townhall's roof can be a different color for each faction, while the rest of the structure are the same; or an orc can hand wrist bands in its faction color, while the rest of its skin and pants are same for all factions.*

In low poly art models where each face is flat shaded, I learnt to use a color atlas. In this way, I can change the atlas (albedo texture) to change the colors; or I can embed all color theme in one albedo texture and offset the UV in the shader.

However, for hand painted texture, I do not know how to change the color once it is painted in. When inspecting assets on asset stores, I see a different albedo map is provided for each faction. However, I cannot think of efficient way to create many maps after the first.

Appreciate any advise on the proper workflow to do this. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
When inspecting assets on the unity store, I find tint mask. I guess that's one way to achieve the "change color" effect, but any idea what "SAM" might be?

[image]